# Select an object behind transparent object

Tags: fabricjs

I have a large triangle that is on top of a small rect. How can I select the rect without first moving the triangle out of the way.
I made a demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/w6wr7pmrx5

Comment: `object.evented = false`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to still have the triangle movable. Is there a way to have the triangle's transparency non-clickable?

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable `perPixelTargetFind: true` on your triangle so that the object's clickable area is determined by the actual object path rather than its bounding box.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#perPixelTargetFind